# How to select the last record by user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I will like to ask how I could select the last record by user in MySQL?

The following is my query string - which obviously did not work:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM team_notes where `username`='$username')
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What ID are selecting on?  Is that _really_ what defines "last" in this context?  What is it doing and why is that "obviously did not work:"?  What were you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you use sub query for this, if you must use it, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM team_notes where `username`='$username') t
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Every sub query must have a table alias.

And I think you also can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM team_notes WHERE `username`='$username' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```